# .htaccess appending query string to internal redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I’m trying to create SEO friendly masked rewrites in .htaccess. The htaccess file works fine on localhost, and my personal server, but seems unfortunately does not work on GoDaddy’s servers. I'm aware that that's already an issue there, But working for a client who's set on using Godaddy as their host.

The issue is that the rewrite seems to be forcing a redirect showing the rewritten querystring in the browser URL bar instead of keeping it internal.
eg.

Rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9-_/]*)$ /index.php?loadPage=$1&mode=cms [L,QSA]
```

Link: `/images` Redirecting to `/images/?loadPage=images&mode=cms`

this “should” stay as `/images/` for the browser. I have copied my short `.htaccess` below, IPs modified for the development block

```
<Files .htaccess>
    deny from all
</Files>

Options -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Stop Old redirection from block below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/old/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]

# Under construction Redirect
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^0.0.0.0
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?old/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) “/old/$1″ [L,QSA]

#Admin utilities rewrite
RewriteRule ^/?admin/?(.*)$ /index.php?loadPage=$1&mode=backend [L,QSA]

#CMS/Frontend rewrites -- this one is failing
RewriteRule ^\/?([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)\/?$ /index.php?loadPage=$1&mode=cms [QSA,L]
```

A hint of potential note is that the displayed url is `/images/?query_string`, NOT `index.php?query_string`, so it's not doing a full redirect, though external requests are receiving a 301 response from the page request.

Comment: Please refer following links or you can also contect to support team    http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/problem-using-htaccess-for-url-rewrite/ and http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/how-do-i-use-htaccess-to-redirect-my-document-root-and-mask-the-url/?sid=&sp=1

Comment: Thank you for the links, unfortunately I investigated both of them and neither seems to apply to my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested anything but simply looking at that line...

```
RewriteRule ^\/?([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)\/?$ /index.php?loadPage=$1&mode=cms [QSA,L]
```

there is a syntax error. The hyphen after the 9 should be escaped as technically that is a range indicator. Most of the time you see people place it at the end before the `]` and so it doesn't cause an error and so most people think they don't have to escape it. You also do not need to escape the forward slashes. Also using the question mark makes the previous optional, and don't know why you want that. So it should be like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/?$ /index\.php?loadPage=$1&mode=cms [QSA,L]
```

Comment: The optional closing slash is because some "fantastic" browser addons remove the trailing slash from links if there is nothing present following the slash (something to do with security). Oddly though, the rewrite does work correctly if I access with the trailing slash, but will not work if it doesn't exist. The original admin rewrite does the same thing (just less picky), and works perfectly, so i think your onto something with how the match values are being interpreted. I'll do some more playing around with it. (unfortunately the suggested changes didn't change the issue).

Comment: I added a 301 redirect for any incoming links that do not have the trailing slash to append it, and got the rules working the way I want them to. Would rather have it optional in one rule, but it works at least, lol. Thanks for putting me on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

I've commented out some of the other rules so you can tell what's happening. You were taking anything not beginning with "old" and rewriting it to the old directory. The rule preceding looks like you were taking everything where you found the word '/old/' and you were redirecting it to itself. You should not receive any requests from `0.0.0.0` ever.

The hyphen in your last rule needs to go to the end of the brackets so Apache isn't looking for a range.

Since we're dealing with `.htaccess` we don't need the preceding slashes if we're not using `REQUEST_URI`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Stop Old redirection from block below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/old/(.*)$
RewriteRule .* %1 [L]

# Under construction Redirect
# RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^0.0.0.0
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?old/
# RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /old/$1 [L,QSA]

#Admin utilities rewrite
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ index.php?loadPage=$1&mode=backend [L,QSA]

#CMS/Frontend rewrites
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^index.php$
RewriteRule ^([A_Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?loadPage=$1&mode=cms [QSA,L]
```

Comment: the 0.0.0.0 IP is a placeholder for the IP i'm accessing the server from for development. I agree I'm being a bit lazy with the hyphen, however Apache can normally figure it out since there is no following range characters. I have tested these changes and unfortunately the issue persists. I have also commented out every rule other than RewriteEngine, and the frontend rewrite, and still the same result, so it doesn't seem to be a rule conflict.