# Unable to rewrite htaccess with multiple query strings

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I want to rewrite the url with multiple string query

Original url

```
www.xxx.com/sale.php?a=sale&&b=product&&c=category
```

Expected url

```
www.xxx.com/sale/a/b/c
```

Wrote the below code in htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^sale/(.*)/?$ sale.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3
```

It seems like the / is not escaped, when i tried to echo the value for 
a, b & c. i got the below output.

```
 $a = $_REQUEST['a'];
 $b = $_REQUEST['b'];
 $a = $_REQUEST['c'];

Output value
a = sale/product/category
b = 
c = 

Expected result

a = sale
b = product
c = category
```

Thanks in advance.

I also tried with the below instance

```
 RewriteRule ^sale/(.*)$ sale.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 

 RewriteRule ^sale/([^/.]+)/?$ sale.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 -> This didnt worked.

 Actual value
 a = sale/product/category
 b = 
 c = 

 Expected result

 a = sale
 b = product
 c = category
```

Comment: How about RewriteRule ^sale/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ sale.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3

Comment: here's a nice tool to test your rules: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: What I think you need is to append the query string parameters using the QSA Flag. see https://stackoverflow.com/q/16908599/80836

Answer (score 0):

This is the actual rule you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?sale/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /sale.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [END]
```

Your code snippet suggests that you are using `php` as a scripting language. That means you can access those values as:

```
<?php
// ...
$a = $_GET['a'];
$b = $_GET['b'];
$c = $_GET['c'];
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).